# texture2D cause Gl_INVALID_OPERATION when glDrawArrays is called

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to use textures in my fragment shader as in the following lines

```
   gl_FragColor =vec4(diffuseReflection+ambientLighting+texture2D(texSampler2D, uvCoordinates).xyz*specularReflection,material0.diffuse.w);
```

however Gl_INVALID_OPERATION error happens in a call to glDrawArrays.

if I omit the texture2D such as

```
   gl_FragColor =vec4(diffuseReflection+ambientLighting+specularReflection,material0.diffuse.w);
```

Then no error happens.

Here are the lines I create my texture

```
    Texture* texture=new Texture();
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(image.data!=0)
    {
        texture->init(image.data,GL_RGB,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image.cols,image.rows);
}
//Texture class is below the post
```

Here are the lines that I make the texture upload

```
   CHECK_GL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));
    texture->bind();
    CHECK_GL(glUniform1i(texture->texSampler2DHandler,GL_TEXTURE0));
```

This is the relevant part of my Texture class:

```
    void Texture::bind() {
  CHECK_GL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID_));
    }

    void Texture::unbind() {
        CHECK_GL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
    }

    void Texture::init(void* data_,GLenum format, GLenum internal_format, GLenum type, GLsizei width,
        GLsizei height, GLint minfilter, GLint magfilter) {

        CHECK_GL(glGenTextures(1, &textureID_));
      bind();
      format_ = format;
      type_ = type;
      width_ = width;
      height_ = height;
      internal_format_ = internal_format;
      CHECK_GL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minfilter));
      CHECK_GL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magfilter));
      CHECK_GL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
      CHECK_GL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
      data(data_);
      unbind();
    }

    void Texture::data(void* data)
    {
        CHECK_GL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format_, width_, height_, 0, format_, type_, data));
    }
```

Comment: if you get error while calling glDrawArrays, have a look at the possible cause at the end of this page: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml

Comment: Is this OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: Most likely, your shader is just not compiling in one case.  It is unclear if your code is valid when the GLSL (ES) version is not known.

Comment: Hi my code is in opengl es and running on desktop thanks to Qt. When there is a syntax error in my glsl compilation it prints out the error message and I can see this with  'glGetProgramInfoLog(program, maxLength, &infologLength, infoLog);
  if (infologLength > 0) {
   Error(std::string("Shader failed to link program: ") + infoLog);
  }'

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
CHECK_GL(glUniform1i(texture->texSampler2DHandler,GL_TEXTURE0));
```

had to be

```
CHECK_GL(glUniform1i(texture->texSampler2DHandler,0));
```